# Set Jupyter Notebook password in bash script through environment variable

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

I have come across the following code in a bash script for automatic deployment and setup of Jupyter Notebook. There are issues when the password contains a `#`, as the rest of the line is treated as a comment (and probably raises an exception in Python due to lack of closing bracket):

```
# Set up Jupyter Notebook with the same password
su - $USERNAME -c "$SHELL +x" << EOF
  mkdir -p ~/.jupyter
  python3 -c "from notebook.auth.security import set_password; set_password(password=\"$PASSWORD\")"
EOF
```

Obviously this is not an ideal way to set a password due to the above issues.

I am wondering what best practice would be in this situation? Using triple-quotes instead of single enclosing quotes might be better, but still runs into issues if the supplied password has triple quotes. How is this situation normally tackled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the password through a bash here-document, just use python to read it from the environment:

```
# Set up Jupyter Notebook with the same password
su - $USERNAME -c "$SHELL +x" << EOF
  mkdir -p ~/.jupyter
  python3 -c "from notebook.auth.security import set_password; import os; set_password(password=os.environ['PASSWORD'])"
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Jupyter command line options[enter link description here](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-command.html) to notebook like its done for docker. The method is save as it will use ths sha. the start-notebook.sh script looks like this:[source](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/base-notebook/start-notebook.sh).

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Jupyter Development Team.
# Distributed under the terms of the Modified BSD License.

set -e

wrapper=""
if [[ "${RESTARTABLE}" == "yes" ]]; then
  wrapper="run-one-constantly"
fi

if [[ ! -z "${JUPYTERHUB_API_TOKEN}" ]]; then
  # launched by JupyterHub, use single-user entrypoint
  exec /usr/local/bin/start-singleuser.sh "$@"
elif [[ ! -z "${JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB}" ]]; then
  . /usr/local/bin/start.sh $wrapper jupyter lab "$@"
else
  . /usr/local/bin/start.sh $wrapper jupyter notebook "$@"
fi
```

For example, to secure the Notebook server with a custom password hashed using IPython.lib.passwd() instead of the default token, you can run the following to test via docker:

```
#generate a password
from IPython.lib.security import passwd
passwd(passphrase=None, algorithm='sha1')


# run test in docker
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 jupyter/base-notebook start-notebook.sh --notebookApp.password='sha1:31246c00022b:cd4a5e1eac6b621284331642a27b621948d80a92'
```